# Make void not execute so that it exists just for the sake of running a function when called

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a movement script and inside it also contains the stamina part. I have a function to drain the stamina but I want to call it only when pressing a button. How can I change the void part so that its wont trigger just when I call the function it defines

Here is my code (the void im talking about is at line 38 called `staminadrain()`)

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CharacterMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool tired;
    public float walkSpeed = 6f;
    public CharacterController _charCont;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    public float stam { get; set; }
    private float currentstam { get; set; }
    public Slider stam_bar;
    public float sprintspeedincrease = 1.5f;
    public float staminadrainvalue = 1.0f;
    public float staminaregenvalue = 1.0f;
    public float tiredpenalty = 0.1f;
    private bool walkspeedreduced;

    public void Start ()
    {
        _charCont = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        stam = 100f;
        currentstam = stam;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
        InvokeRepeating("staminadrain", 1.0f, 1f);
        InvokeRepeating("staminaregen", 1.0f, 0.5f);
    }

    void staminaregen()
    {
        currentstam += staminaregenvalue;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
    }

    void staminadrain()
    {
        currentstam -= staminadrainvalue;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
        if(currentstam <= 0)
        {
            tired = true;
        }
    }

    float calculateStam()
    {
        return currentstam / stam;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(tired == true)
        {
            walkSpeed = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tired = false;
            walkSpeed = 6;
        }

        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) && (0 <= currentstam))
        {
            walkSpeed *= sprintspeedincrease;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            staminadrain();
        }

        if ((Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)) && (0 <= currentstam))
        {
            walkSpeed /= sprintspeedincrease;
            staminaregen();
        }

        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= walkSpeed;

        moveDirection.y = gravity;
        _charCont.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Maybe remove the `InvokeRepeating` or add an additional bool flag? In general I would preferre Coroutines

Comment: Set a Boolean when the key is down and it when it’s not?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood what you want but from your code I guess:

You want `staminaregen` and `staminadrain` to be called repeatedly but only after a certain button is pressed.

First this check makes no sense

```c#
    if(tired == true)
    {
        walkSpeed = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        tired = false;
        walkSpeed = 6;
    }
```

So, if `tired == true` it stays `true` forever? And if `tired == false` it stays `false` and the `walkspeed` is fixed to `6` every frame so increasing it later will not have much effect. I would remove this and do it in the routines below.

---

In general instead of polling states and react to them in `Update`  would rather use [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) here and remove these lines

```c#
InvokeRepeating("staminadrain", 1.0f, 1f);
InvokeRepeating("staminaregen", 1.0f, 0.5f);
```

then have the two routines like

```c#
private IEnumerator StaminaRegen()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    while(!Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        currentstam += staminaregenvalue;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();

        // Maximum reached?
        if(currentStam >= 100)
        {
            currentStam = 100;
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

void StaminaDrain()
{
    while(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        currentstam -= staminadrainvalue;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
        if(currentstam <= 0)
        {
            walkspeed = 0;
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can start these routines via your buttons

```c#
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    if(currentStamina > 0) walkSpeed *= sprintspeedincrease;

    StartCoroutine (StaminaDrain());
}

if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    StopAllCoroutines();

    if(currentStamina == 0)
    {
        walkSpeed = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        walkSpeed /= sprintspeedincrease;
    }

    StartCoroutine (StaminaRegen());
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to handle this. **InvokeRepeating("staminadrain", 1.0f, 1f)** simply means that the following will be called on the frame every second:

```
void staminadrain()
    {
        currentstam -= staminadrainvalue;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
        if(currentstam <= 0)
        {
            tired = true;
        }
    }
```

If you want to have your stamina only drain when pressing a button, you could add a line of code that returns early if the button is not pressed (Assuming "Sprint" is configured as "left shift" in your input manager):

```
        if(!Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
            return;
```

This makes your code:

```
void staminadrain()
    {
        if(!Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
            return;
        currentstam -= staminadrainvalue;
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
        if(currentstam <= 0)
        {
            tired = true;
        }
    }
```

However, using InvokeRepeating seems like a poor decision since you are already using Update. It might be more useful to use Coroutines mentioned by DerHugo. Here's how I would use Coroutines to make my character drain stamina when the sprint button is pressed:

```
bool sprinting;

IEnumerator DrainStamina()
{
    //If you don't have the stamina to sprint, exit the coroutine early
    if(currentstam <= 0)
        yield break;
    while(Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
    {
        sprinting = true;
        //Calculate the fraction of stamina lost since last frame
        currentstam -= staminadrainvalue / Time.deltaTime; 
        stam_bar.value = calculateStam();
        if(currentstam <= 0)
        {
            currentstam = 0;
            tired = true;
            //Exit the coroutine early if stamina is at or below 0 while you are still holding down sprint
            sprinting = false;
            yield break;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Now in your Update code, whenever you press the sprint button down, start the DrainStamina Coroutine:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtomDown("Sprint")
        StartCoroutine(DrainStamina());
}
```

---

This all being said, there's a lot of stuff I would change to your code. Here's what I've gathered on what you're trying to do:

- If you're walking, your movespeed is 6 units/second. I don't see a need to use CharacterController over RigidBody here, especially as you're simulating gravity.
- If you're sprinting, your movespeed is 1.5x your walk speed.
- You have a tired penalty, but you're not using it. I'm assuming if you're tired, your move speed is tiredPenaltyx your walk speed. Here's how I would code it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CharacterMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed = 6f;
    //You'll need to add the rigidBody to your gameObject, and configure your gravity/weight/etc there.
    public RigidBody rb;
    public float maxStamina = 100f;
    //SluggishRecoveryThreshold is the stamina level at which you return to normal walk speed and not sluggish
    public float sluggishRecoveryThreshold = 30f;
    public float sprintMult = 1.5f;
    public float tiredMult = 0.9f;
    public float staminaDrainRate = 1.0f;
    public float staminaRegenRate = 1.0f;
    public Slider stam_bar; 

    MoveState moveState;
    float stamina;

    enum MoveState
    {
        Walking,
        Sprinting,
        Sluggish
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }

    public void Start ()
    {
        stamina = maxStamina;
        moveState = MoveState.Walking;
        stam_bar.value = stamina / maxStamina;
    }

    void Update()
    {        
        //On the first frame that you push the sprint button, start the sprint coroutine
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
            StartCoroutine(Sprint());

        //If you're not currently sprinting, regen stamina
        if(moveState != MoveState.Sprinting)
        {
            stamina += staminaRegenRate/ Time.deltaTime; 
            if(stamina > maxStamina)
                stamina = maxStamina;
        }

        //If you're currently sluggish, check to see if you can stop being sluggish
        if(moveState == MoveState.Sluggish)
        {
            if(stamina > sluggishRecoveryThreshold)
               moveState = MoveState.Walking;
        }

        stam_bar.value = stamina / maxStamina;

        //Determine the move speed multiplier based on the current move state.
        float moveMult = 1f;
        if(moveState == MoveState.Sprinting)
            moveMult = sprintMult;
        if(moveState == MoveState.Sluggish)
            moveMult = tiredMult;

        //Determine the move direction based on axis input
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        Vectory3 moveVector = moveDirection * walkSpeed * moveMult;

        //move the character by changing rigidbody velocity, but do not affect the y vector to allow gravity to continue to act.
        Vector3 rbVelocity = rb.velocity;
        rbVelocity.x = moveVector.x;
        rbVelcoity.z = moveVector.z;
        rb.velocity = rbVelocity;
    }

    IEnumerator Sprinting()
    {
        //If you don't have the stamina to sprint, exit the coroutine early
        if(stamina <= 0)
            yield break;
        while(Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
        {
            moveState = MoveState.Sprinting;
            //Calculate the fraction of stamina lost since last frame
            stamina -= staminaDrainRate / Time.deltaTime; 

            if(currentstam <= 0)
            {
                stamina = 0;
                //Exit the coroutine early and mark character as sluggish
                moveState = MoveState.Sluggish;
                yield break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    //Disclaimer: This wall all written in browser and not tested. Please let me know if you find any syntax errors.
}
```